# player rectangle not moving

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

# Initializations
game = True
pygame.init()
FPS = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,800))
screen.fill((0,0,0))

# Player
pX = 300
pY = 400
pClr = ((255,255,255))
def Player(plr):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, pClr, plr)

while game:
    player = pygame.Rect(pX,pY,25,25)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game = False
        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            while event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pX -= 50

    Player(player)
    
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()
```

for some reason when I press the right key it doesn't move the player, but when printing it works just fine. sorry for asking this beginner question on here.

tried redrawing the player expecting it to move but no avail.

Comment: You are not modifying `player` so why would it change?

Comment: You're not updating the player rectangle after it's created.

Answer (score -1):

Change `while` in this line to `if`

```
while event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
```

Like this:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
```

Because the `event.key` value doesn't change this frame, so the code with `while` will just run an infinite loop.

And you need to add

```
screen.fill((0, 0, 0)
```

Before drawing anything, because otherwise the rectangle will show a trail

```
import pygame

# Initializations
game = True
pygame.init()
FPS = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,800))
screen.fill((0,0,0))

# Player
pX = 300
pY = 400
pClr = ((255,255,255))
def Player(plr):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, pClr, plr)

while game:
    player = pygame.Rect(pX,pY,25,25)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pX -= 50

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    Player(player)

    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
```